# Console setting for displaying hex numbers

Tags: javascript, console

I've just noticed that when logging a data structure which contains a hexadecimal string value to the console, it output's the field as 1, instead of the string value. This is happening in Chrome and Safari.

[image]

At the top of the screenshot, you can see an object being logged, this object has an  '_id' field, this string is a MongoDb ObjectId, in a nutshell, it's a hexadecimal string.

You can see at the top of the screenshot that the _id field contains a string but when it's (the object) value is being printed (the expanded view), it's being displayed as (Number) 1.

The second log is me console.log'ing the value explicitly, i.e.

```
//Where obj is the object being logged in the screenshot.
console.log(obj.data._id);
```

Unsure exactly what's happening here, I can't see how the value being logged would be output as Number 1, that is not the base 10 value of the hexadecimal string, the console is surely making some assumption about the value, and processing it, unsure exactly what's going on there though.

**So my question is**

Why is 1 being printed here?

Comment: It might be a timing issue, when the item is first logged its value may indeed have been `5afb...`, but by the time you get to expand the view in the console logged it's been mapped to `1`..   When you log something in Chrome it's reference is held, IOW: It becomes a live view of the object.  ps.. It's common problem with Chromes console log,..

Comment: Is there any reproducible example? My best guess is you are doing something you are simply not describing here and therefore answering this question may be impossible.

Comment: Sorry, this was me, I put a hard coded `1` :)

Comment: True story dat ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what else has happened to the object after it's been sent to the console, I'm assuming what you are seeing here is how Chrome's console log keeps a reference to the object, it doesn't hold a snapshot at the time of console logging, but a live reference to the object.

Below is a simple example.

Open up Chromes console,. you will see `{x: "one"}`,  but when you expand the object you will see `x: 1` and not `x: "one"`..

```js
var a = {
  x: "one"
};

console.log(a);

a.x = 1;
```